# merging 2 pdf's and rearanging pages

Tags: pdfpages

This is not just merging two `pdf` files using `pdflatex`.

final document need have a structure:

- odd pages are from `first.pdf`
- even pages are from `second.pdf`

is this possible?

p.s.
I'm trying to have 4 column parallel text spread on 2 pages. follow this
[Four Language Parallel Column Book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36453/four-language-parallel-column-book)
have 2 documents one for odd another for even pages...
can there be a better solution ?

Comment: Please this blog post about using pdftk (not latex) for [Interleaving two PDF files](http://binarystatic.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/interleaving-two-pdf-files/)

Comment: Does `first.pdf` have the same number of pages as `second.pdf`? Are the pages in `first.pdf` odd-numbered and `second.pdf` even-numbered? Should this be a pure LaTeX solution?

Comment: You can recycle code from my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65961/independent-columns-environment/65978#65978

Comment: "Should this be a pure LaTeX solution?" If I can spread 4 columns on 2 pages--this can be pure latex. If pdflatex can split and rearrange 2 pdf files this also be nice... but it seems pdftk way is a solution.

Comment: Today instead of `pdftk` this can also be done with `pdfunite` and `pdfseparate` from poppler utils.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar task in the past. My solution was to write a script heavily using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) toolkit, in my case on Linux (pdftk is included in most full-fledged distributions).

The solution in your case would be to first *split the two documents into separate pdfs one per page* and subsequently *merge them into a single one*.

I guess, with some command line literacy, looking at the [examples](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) should be enough to come up with your solution. Alternatively, if this is a one-time job and you really are after a GUI-based solution, you can split the document into separate pages using your favorite PDF viewer and simply print each page into a separate pdf file on your disk. Subsequently you could concatenate the files back again using a tool such as e.g., [PDFedit](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html).

Comment: Thanks to all...Actual problem is as mentioned in other thread spreading 4 column sincronized text on 2 pages... it seems only with 2 separate pdf's can help with pdftk or directly editing pdf with pdfedit