# Two-column text-figure layout with memoir

Tags: memoir

I am new to the memoir documentclass, and I'm attempting to learn it to typeset some lecture notes.  I would like for the lecture notes to have a single column of text on the left of each page, and a single column for accompanying figures on the right of each page.  Is there a nice, simple way to accomplish this in memoir?

Comment: Increase the right margin and use marginfigures!

Comment: I don't think `memoir` (or any of the standard classes) are designed to do this exactly unless you do what @HarishKumar suggests.  There is the `parcolumns` package, which might also be of some help. Here's a similar question to yours: [Independent Columns Environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65961)

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks.  A quick scan of the sidenotes package documentation makes me feel like that might be just the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: Also of interest is the flowfram package.  But if you want to align the figures on the right with text on the left, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195155/alignment-of-text-in-two-columns-forcing-empty-lines-in-one-to-avoid-collision/195347#195347.